# Unity | instantiate only works once

Tags: unity-game-engine

For some reason whenever I Instantiate, I can only instantiate once per build/run/game. I've tried to see if it was that I could only use different prefabs, but that isn't it. Please help, I've been trying to find an answer but no one seems to have the same problem. Thanks for reading this.

heres [the project (assets and project settings)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Hk3clOIVtyYDY_zTjOGYi-60oKo5ozo/view?usp=sharing) if you wanna mess around with it yourself

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreatePipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Pipe;
    public bool yes = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("initializationn");
        Debug.Log("started");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // if (yes){
        //     inst();
        //     yes = false;
        // }
        
    }

    public IEnumerator initializationn()
    {
        
        Debug.Log("started");
        inst();
        // yes = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        inst();
        // yes = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        inst();
        // yes = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        // while (true){
        //     inst()
        //     yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        // }
    
    }
    public void inst(){
        Debug.Log("in");
        var g  = Instantiate(Pipe, new Vector3(7f, Random.Range(-6.5f,0f), 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        g.SetActive(true);
        g.name = "Pipe";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: could you share your project? The issue is - besides the here mentioned potential improvements - definitely coming from somewhere else ;)

Comment: Are you manipulating the Time Scale in another script?

Comment: @derHugo https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Hk3clOIVtyYDY_zTjOGYi-60oKo5ozo/view?usp=sharing have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason only one pipe exist at at time is that the script "PipeStuff" you attached to the Prefab "Pipe", makes it a singleton. So every time you create a duplicate instance you are deleting that object since a "PipeStuff" already exist.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Suggestions:**

Your script is absolutely fine there is no problem with it but perhaps you are destroying that gameObject which is intantiating those pipe prefabs thats why its not working as you intend it to, any ways check if it is so because there seems to be no other problem with your script and also you can do it in one more way by using invokeRepeating function too like:

```cs
    InvokeRepeating( nameof(inst), 0, 3 );
```

it will call this function repeatadely after every 3 seconds and the first parameter which is 0, is used for delay at the start so if you want to Invoke that function after some seconds you can do so as well and when you are done you can destroy or disable that gameObject too, its just a basic way of doing so otherwise there are tons of ways to do so anyways...

Hope it helps... Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for being way to helpful and an amazing person, but I am still have trouble as it still only instantiates it the first time but not any other time
also here is what happens in game https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lcG2h5Jbtuh6hAvuzoktDg56laOSR5KZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: p.s. I dont have any error and I'm working on 2020.3.33

Comment: You are very welcome and I am really sorry I can't really download the file you sent me, but anyways as I said just check if your gameObject is gettings destroyed or disabled or not, or else you can debug it very easily using unity's built in function like "OnDisable" and "On Destroy" just use any kind of "Debug.Log()" in those functions to see if it is getting disabled or destroyed or not... and ofcourse the gameObject is calling the function by itself so if it is disabled and destroyed it won't show any errors, it will just stop the script execution

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I didn't do that but I figured out that I need to destroy my gameObject before instantiating a new one? Thats very frustrating, also I upgraded the project 2021 unity, it is still having the problems, which unity version are you using, as you said that it waws fine for you. Also, it is a GameObject that has the script on it, not one of the pipes.

Comment: That is a great code improvement / refactor suggestion ... but it doesn't really address the question. I would claim this is worth a comment, not an answer

Comment: the thing that I meant to say is that your perhaps gameObject is getting destroyed thats why you can't instantiate more objects it has nothing to do with destroying one instantiated object and then instantiating a new one, thats why I suggested to try out by debugging if your gameObject has any issue or not

Comment: @Sherry I have no issue with my game object, its just that every time I ask for it to instantiate it will immediately get destroyed after.

Comment: So thats what I meant to say the whole time, because its getting destroyed after the instantiation it wasn't instantiating more prefabs, but anyways glad you found solution for yourself... Happy Coding :)